# Mocha Chai regex are equals

Tags: regex, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test the behaviour of a method that produce regex.

Using Mocha/Chai test suite I have the following code :

```
describe('regexTest',function () {
  it('should return a regexp', function () {
    var regex = regexTest();
    assert.equal(regex, /someregex/);
  });
});
```

But it seems that the code above doesn't work. I tried in the chrome console :

```
/a/ == /a/ 
> false
```

For the moment the only way I found is to compare the `toString` of the two regex (that should be equals and that I can compare) :

```
describe('regexTest',function () {
  it('should return a regexp', function () {
    var regex = regexTest();
    assert.equal(regex.toString(), '/someregex/');
  });
});
```

Do you know a *better* way to do this ? Because I find this not really clean ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since regular expression is an object, you need to use deep equals to compare 2 regex objects with each other

```
expect(/a/).to.be.deep.equal(/a/, 'should match')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I test if a literal regexp is valid:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('RegExp Test', function() {
  it('should return a valid RegExp', function() {
    var getSomeRegex = function() {
      return /someregex/;
    };

    var aRegex = getSomeRegex();
    assert.equal(aRegex instanceof RegExp, true);
  });

  it('should return a invalid Regexp', function() {
    var getInvalidRegex = function() {
      return '/something';
    };

    var aInvalidRegex = getInvalidRegex();
    assert.equal(aInvalidRegex instanceof RegExp, false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I will add such verification. But the original purpose of this post was to check if two regex are equals...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but for anyone else who stumbles across this on Google way I did, Chai's normal comparison functions work with Regexp objects too...

```
const re = new RegExp( '^foo.*bar$', 'i' );
re.should.eql( /^foo.*bar$/i );
```

Comment: `.eql` is a deep equal comparison, as stated by @PirateApp